# HTML/CSS: How do I keep multiple divs inline horizontally in header?

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a webpage, and I'm having a problem with my header. The header I'm making has four elements:

- The header background.
- The website logo (top left)
- The website title (center)
- The login button for the website's application portal

My problem is everything keeps aligning vertically. I'm going to link a screenshot below to a temporary page that I made to try and work out this issue below. I can't seem to figure it out.

I should add that I did get everything to look good using float. By having all three "inner" elements (everything except for the background) be floating, they lined up properly. Unfortunately, that works terrible when the page is resized. If it's anything less than a certain height, the components slip out of alignment.

Here is my HTML/CSS code. Any help would be appreciated. Can't seem to figure this out.

```css
.header{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px gray;
}

/* Title Text in Header */
.header-title{
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 5px gray;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

/* Logo Div */
.logo{
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px gray;
}

/* Div in Header for User Status/Login/Logout/Etc */
.user-status{
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

/* Header Style for welcome page */
.header-welcome{
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
}

.btn-link{
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.btn-link:hover{
  border: solid 1px blue;
  border-radius: 10%;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header header-welcome">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="./img/ehslogo.png" height="70px"/>
  </div>
  <div class="header-title">
    <h1>Temp Title</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="user-status">
    <form method="get">
      <input class="btn-link" type="submit" 
             name="loginButton" 
             value="Login Button"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot - Here you can see the components aligned vertically. What I want is for all three to fit horizontally inside the orange bar at the top. The logo should NOT be as wide as it is.

[image]

Comment: if a div has a specific width or is `display:inline-block` you can try to center it with `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: `margin auto` will have no effect on an `inline-block` element. You would need to set `text-align:center` on the parent for that.

Answer (score 1):

Add the css rule `.header-welcome> div{display: inline-block;}`

```css
/* Header Style for welcome page */
.header-welcome{
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
}
/*Rule add*/
.header-welcome> div{display: inline-block;}
/* Logo Div */
.logo{
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px gray;
}

/* Div in Header for User Status/Login/Logout/Etc */
.user-status{
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}


.btn-link{
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.btn-link:hover{
  border: solid 1px blue;
  border-radius: 10%;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header header-welcome">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="./img/ehslogo.png" height="70px"/>
  </div>
  <div class="header-title">
    <h1>Temp Title</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="user-status">
    <form method="get">
      <input class="btn-link" type="submit" 
             name="loginButton" 
             value="Login Button"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```